# How to dynamically compute value of a variable and use it in a command?

Tags: bash, shell, csh

Reducing what I'm trying to do to a simple example:

```
env temp=`pwd` echo "$temp"
```

I get this message:

```
temp: Undefined variable.
```

How do I make it work (in a shell-agnostic way)? I'm expecting the result of `pwd` to be printed.

My actual requirement uses a complicated expression in place of `pwd`, a script in place of "`echo`", and the variable `$temp` as an argument to that script.

Also, I want to set this variable only for this single command, and not for the whole shell (or any subsequent subshells).

Comment: Why do you need this? The shell expands `$temp` before the command is run, so the contents of the environment are irrelevant.

Comment: @jonathan-leffler I think this is a dupe of the `bash` part, but not of the `csh` part.

Comment: The correct answer to the `csh` part is "Don't use the sea-shell; leave sea-shells on the sea-shore (where, with any luck, the tide will wash them away)".  It is not clear why the code tries to pass `temp` as both an argument and an environment variable.  If it's a complicated command instead of `pwd` and script instead of `echo`, the whole thing should be wrapped up in a script, and the script should be a Bourne/Korn/POSIX/Bash shell script and not a C shell script.

Comment: This came to mind: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/ but I assumed there was a good reason to require `csh` in the original question.

Comment: @chepner, Ah, I didn't know the sequence in which bash expand variables - that explains it. Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am aware of the pitfalls with C shell scripting (still, thanks for the reminder). I just wanted a portable solution since its users use all kinds of interactive shells. Perhaps it's best to write a wrapper script than a super complicated one-liner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this for `sh` and `bash`

```
(export temp=`pwd`; echo $temp)
```

And this for `csh`

```
csh -c 'setenv temp `pwd`; echo "$temp"'
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I do it in command line so it could work on say both csh and bash?

Comment: Please see my revised answer.